# prestashop 1.6 addJsDef not working

Tags: smarty, prestashop

i updated prestashop from 1.5 to 1.6, now the theme have some little issue, the most important is that the price of the combinations is 0 in the product page. I tried to update the theme but everything declared with {addJsDef} is absent from the source code. Do you have any suggestion please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm digging an old issue here, but maybe that could help someone in the future :

As said on this thread of the Prestashop forums : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/357269-prestashop-16-addjsdef-not-working/ , try to force the add of the Prestashop JS Files in the footer of your page in the back office.

Back Office -> Advanced Params -> Performance -> Activate Javascript to end

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your theme has layout.tpl file

Without this the following if statement fails in the classes/Controller/Controller.php

```
if (in_array($this->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront')) && !empty($html) && $this->getLayout()) {
```

or your js won't be loaded into the defer variable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason that there is no definition in the pattern of these variables?
Try adding this code in header.tpl:

```
{if isset($js_defer) && !$js_defer && isset($js_files) && isset($js_def)}
{$js_def}
{foreach from=$js_files item=js_uri}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$js_uri|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"></script>
{/foreach}
{/if}
```